# Python : Merge several columns of a dataframe without having duplicates of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, duplicates

Let's say that I have this dataframe :

```
Name = ['Lolo', 'Mike', 'Tobias','Luke','Sam']
Age = [19, 34, 13, 45, 52]
Info_1 = ['Tall', 'Large', 'Small', 'Small','']
Info_2 = ['New York', 'Paris', 'Lisbon', '', 'Berlin']
Info_3 = ['Tall', 'Paris', 'Hi', 'Small', 'Thanks']
Data = [123,268,76,909,87]
Sex = ['F', 'M', 'M','M','M']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : Name, 'Age' : Age, 'Info_1' : Info_1, 'Info_2' : Info_2, 'Info_3' : Info_3, 'Data' : Data, 'Sex' : Sex})

print(df)

     Name  Age Info_1    Info_2  Info_3  Data Sex
0    Lolo   19   Tall  New York    Tall   123   F
1    Mike   34  Large     Paris   Paris   268   M
2  Tobias   13  Small    Lisbon      Hi    76   M
3    Luke   45  Small             Small   909   M
4     Sam   52           Berlin  Thanks    87   M
```

I want to merge the data of four columns of this dataframe : Info_1, Info_2, Info_3, Data.
I want to merge them without having duplicates of data for each row. That means for the row "0", I do not want to have "Tall" twice. So at the end I would like to get something like that :

```
     Name  Age                Info Sex
0    Lolo   19   Tall New York 123   F
1    Mike   34     Large Paris 268   M
2  Tobias   13  Small Lisbon Hi 76   M
3    Luke   45           Small 909   M
4     Sam   52    Berlin Thanks 87   M
```

I tried this function to merge the data :

```
di['period'] = df[['Info_1', 'Info_2', 'Info_3' 'Data']].agg('-'.join, axis=1)
```

However I get an error because it expects a string, How can I merge the data of the column "Data" ? And how can I check that I do not create duplicates

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Data` columns seems to be `int` type. Convert it to strings first:

```
df['Data'] = df['Data'].astype(str)
df['period'] = (df[['Info_1','Info_2','Info_3','Data']]
                   .apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x[x!=''].unique()), axis=1)
               )
```

Output:

```
     Name  Age Info_1    Info_2  Info_3 Data Sex              period
0    Lolo   19   Tall  New York    Tall  123   F   Tall New York 123
1    Mike   34  Large     Paris   Paris  268   M     Large Paris 268
2  Tobias   13  Small    Lisbon      Hi   76   M  Small Lisbon Hi 76
3    Luke   45  Small             Small  909   M           Small 909
4     Sam   52           Berlin  Thanks   87   M    Berlin Thanks 87
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's probably easiest to first just concatenate all the fields you want with a space in between:

```
df['Info'] = df.Info_1 + ' ' +  df.Info_2 + ' ' + df.Info_3 + ' ' + df.Data.astype(str)
```

Then you can write a function to remove the duplicate words from a string, something like this:

```
def remove_dup_words(s):
    words = s.split(' ')
    unique_words = pd.Series(words).drop_duplicates().tolist()
    return ' '.join(unique_words)
```

and apply that function to the `Info` field:

```
df['Info'] = df.Info.apply(remove_dup_words)
```

all the code together:

```
import pandas as pd

def remove_dup_words(s):
    words = s.split(' ')
    unique_words = pd.Series(words).drop_duplicates().tolist()
    return ' '.join(unique_words)

Name = ['Lolo', 'Mike', 'Tobias','Luke','Sam']
Age = [19, 34, 13, 45, 52]
Info_1 = ['Tall', 'Large', 'Small', 'Small','']
Info_2 = ['New York', 'Paris', 'Lisbon', '', 'Berlin']
Info_3 = ['Tall', 'Paris', 'Hi', 'Small', 'Thanks']
Data = [123,268,76,909,87]
Sex = ['F', 'M', 'M','M','M']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : Name, 'Age' : Age, 'Info_1' : Info_1, 'Info_2' : Info_2, 'Info_3' : Info_3, 'Data' : Data, 'Sex' : Sex})

df['Info'] = df.Info_1 + ' ' +  df.Info_2 + ' ' + df.Info_3 + ' ' + df.Data.astype(str)
df['Info'] = df.Info.apply(remove_dup_words)

print(df)

     Name  Age Info_1    Info_2  Info_3  Data Sex                Info
0    Lolo   19   Tall  New York    Tall   123   F   Tall New York 123
1    Mike   34  Large     Paris   Paris   268   M     Large Paris 268
2  Tobias   13  Small    Lisbon      Hi    76   M  Small Lisbon Hi 76
3    Luke   45  Small             Small   909   M          Small  909
4     Sam   52           Berlin  Thanks    87   M    Berlin Thanks 87
```